# Google App Engine: Map parameter becomes JSonMap

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I have the following method on in my endpoint:

```
public void test(Map<Long, List<String>> map) {
    //do something with the map
}
```

but the generated code requires a JsonMap which is basically a `Map<String, Object>`. So I have to put my map into a JsonMap.

```
import com.example.mymodule.backend.endpointName.model.JsonMap
.
.
.
public void someMethod(Map mappings) {
    JsonMap map = new JsonMap();
    for (Map.Entry<Long, List<String>> e : mappings.entrySet()) {
        map.put(String.valueOf(e.getKey()), e.getValue());
    }
    endpointServiceHandle.endpoint().test(map).execute();
}
```

It seems to work until it reaches the end of the `mappings` (during iteration) in the endpoint. In the last `Key,Value` pair the `Key` isn't a `long` and  value isn't a `List<String>` but both are rather a `String`.

Basically: **How can I use a Map of Long and List pairs as a parameter?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're going about this in a strange way. Have you [read the docs on endpoints in Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types)? The valid parameter types include any java.util.Collection. You could simply send everything as a Map of strings and parse the longs/strings depending on what your application needs. It seems that the last key value pair fails because the types in your map don't correspond to how you are referencing them, as you noted.

Comment: Thanks. A few questions though: [1] What do you mean by I'm going about it in a strange way? What would be a better alternative to pass a key value pair of `Long` and `List<String>`. [2] If I can pass any collection I should be able to pass a List<Long> but I get `Invalid long value: '5730082031140864,5730082031140864'` it doesn't seem to split it. (I'm using the client libraries Android Studio generates to call it).